# grouping data from db with same id in same div tag

Tags: php, mysqli

[i want to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXQbO.jpg)

[my database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y50rG.png)

I want to display the data in the same `<div>` group by the id. how do I do this? please refer on the image since I'm bad in explaining..

this is some of my code that I have tried. I have no idea how to do this

```
<?php 

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT tblstudent.studentId,tblstudent.programme,tblstudent.cgpa,tblpersonalinfo.studentId,tblpersonalinfo.pImage,tblpersonalinfo.pImageType,tblpersonalinfo.pImageSize,tblpersonalinfo.pName,tblskill.skill FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN tblpersonalinfo ON tblstudent.studentId = tblpersonalinfo.studentId INNER JOIN tblskill ON tblpersonalinfo.studentId = tblskill.studentId ".$where_sql."  ");

  if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

      echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='0' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
      echo "<tbody>";

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


 // get data from db


  echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo '<div  class="title bg-primary" align="left" style="font-weight: bold;">' .   '&nbsp;' . '<img src="uploads/' . $row['pImage'] .' " alt = "avatar" height="60" width="50" >' . '&nbsp;' . $row['pName'] .  '</div>';
  echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['programme']. '</div>';

  if ($row[0] == $row[0] ) {

  echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='1' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['skill']. '</div>';
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</tbody>";
  echo "</table>";
  }
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You should try hard to explain, because people who want to help do not want to go get information elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
<?php 

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT tblstudent.studentId,tblstudent.programme,tblstudent.cgpa,tblpersonalinfo.studentId,tblpersonalinfo.pImage,tblpersonalinfo.pImageType,tblpersonalinfo.pImageSize,tblpersonalinfo.pName,tblskill.skill FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN tblpersonalinfo ON tblstudent.studentId = tblpersonalinfo.studentId INNER JOIN tblskill ON tblpersonalinfo.studentId = tblskill.studentId ".$where_sql."  ");

if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

    echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='0' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    $flag = true;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         // get data from db
        if($flag){

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo '<div  class="title bg-primary" align="left" style="font-weight: bold;">' .   '&nbsp;' . '<img src="uploads/' . $row['pImage'] .' " alt = "avatar" height="60" width="50" >' . '&nbsp;' . $row['pName'] .  '</div>';
            echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['programme']. '</div>';


            echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='1' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            $flag=false;
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['skill']. '</div>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

You should make sure that only `<tr></tr>` code gets repeated in the `while` loop. Rest everything should get displayed only once.

Comment: thnx..the code working but i need few modification since the button got displayed multiple like the data

Answer (score 0):

You have to pre-process the query results. Something like this:

```
$user = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{
    if( !isset($user['id']) )
    {
        $user['id'] = $row['studentId'];
        // Add here all the other fields you want
        $user['prg'] = array();
    }
    $user['prg'][] = array( 'skill'=>$row['skill'], 'proficiency'=>$row['proficiency'] );
}
```

The you can output your table:

```
echo '<table>';
(...)
foreach( $user['prg'] as $prg )
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$prg[skill]}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
(...)
echo '</table>';
```

#### Explanation:

By your SQL query you obtain multiple rows, with repeating fields (user id etc...). You add these fields only at the first loop of `while` (after the `$user[id]` is already set). The values of `skill` and `proficiency` are added to sub-array `$user[prg]` at each loop. So, when you output the table, you will process a single array instead of multiple rows and you will limit the loop to `$user[prg]` sub-array.

#### Alternative:

Another way is to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in your MySQL query.

Comment: i have tried your code but still got some error..i;ll try figure out after i finished modify answer given by P.Jairaj....thnx anyway

Comment: just the curly bracer since i have to match them with my full code.. i'll try ur code again after this..ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

    echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='0' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    $buffer = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // get data from db

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";

    if($buffer != $row[0]){

        echo '<div  class="title bg-primary" align="left" style="font-weight: bold;">' .   '&nbsp;' . '<img src="uploads/' . $row['pImage'] .' " alt = "avatar" height="60" width="50" >' . '&nbsp;' . $row['pName'] .  '</div>';
        $buffer = $row[0];
    }

    echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['programme']. '</div>';

    if ($row[0] == $row[0] ) {

        echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='1' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['skill']. '</div>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx anyway..but your code gove output exactly like my output xD